# Squeezing theorem and sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

we are given that $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are all real sequences for all natural numbers N. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {c_n}$ converge absolutely (note: it is not stated that they have the same limit), $a_n\le{b_n}\le{c_n}$ for all n. Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {b_n}$ converges

I think I know the answer but it seems to simple:

I can quote the theorem on absolute convergence implying convergence. Then I can say $a_n$ converges to L and $c_n$ converges to K and so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {b_n}$ can not converge to anything less than L or anything more than K. L and K are finite and therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {b_n}$ converges to a finite value.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $|b_n|\le \text{max}\,(|a_n|,|c_n|)\le|a_n|+|c_n|$.